# Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple, Version=0.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-standard-2.0

I have an ASP.NET MVC .net Framework 4.7 web application targeting a .net Standard 2.0 library that utilizes EntityFrameworkCore. I am getting this error when trying to run the project. I have tried to enable the auto binding redirects and inserting manual binding redirects. The manual ones at least gave me that it was looking for a different version number but still same error. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you  add `System.ValueTuple` nuget package to use it ?

Comment: @Shyju yes I did. I've tried various package combinations also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded my .NET from 4.7 to 4.7.1 that is installed on my computer. This seems to have fixed the issue

Answer (score -1):

I was having the exact same problem occurring on my testserver and not on my local computer.
After installing .Net framework 4.7.1 on my test server the problem was solved.